# capturing images from camera and setting into listview in android

Tags: java, android, image, listview

### What i am doing::

- I am opening a camera onclick of item from actionbar menu
- I am capturing the image and setting it in a listview

### What is happening::

- Say i have captured 10 images and set it in listview
- next time i run my code, i am able to find the images i took last
  time, and it dosen't start from groundup

### What i am trying to do:

- say i captured 10 images and set in listview
- next time i start the app and start capturing the image it should add
  freshly captured images to listview and not display the old images
- i am not telling i have to delete these images but i the app i want
  to show newly captured images everytime

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 20;
    ArrayList<String> listOfImages;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DisplayCapturedImagesFromCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_camera) {
            startCameraCapture();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void startCameraCapture() {

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);     
         if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

             File photoFile = null;
                try {
                     photoFile = CreateImageFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(photoFile != null)
                {
                    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);                                   
                }               
            }       
    }

    private File CreateImageFile() throws IOException
    {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "Image_" + timeStamp + "_";

        File storageDirectory = getExternalFilesDir("");    
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg",storageDirectory);       
        return image;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        switch(requestCode)
        {
        case CAMERA_CAPTURE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                DisplayCapturedImagesFromCamera();              
            }
            break;
        }

    }

    private void DisplayCapturedImagesFromCamera() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File myPath = getExternalFilesDir(null);
        listOfImages = new ArrayList<String>();

         try
         {

        for(File f: myPath.listFiles()) {
            listOfImages.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        AdptAddjobsGallery adapter = new AdptAddjobsGallery(MainActivity.this,listOfImages);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
             Log.w("Error", ex.getMessage());
         }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        // custom dialog
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.cust_dialog);
                    dialog.setTitle("Image ");

                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listOfImages.get(position));

                    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                    ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
                    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog

                    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });

                    dialog.show();  
    }
```

}

**AdptAddjobsGallery.java**

```
public class AdptAddjobsGallery extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;

    private final ArrayList<String> listOfImages;

    public AdptAddjobsGallery(Activity context, ArrayList<String> listOfImages) {
        super(context, R.layout.adpt_addjobs_gallery, listOfImages);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context=context;
        this.listOfImages = listOfImages;

    }

    public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if(view == null)
        {       
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.adpt_addjobs_gallery, null,true);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.selfie);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fileName);
        view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }


        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listOfImages.get(position));       
        File f = new File(listOfImages.get(position));  

        holder.txtTitle.setText(f.getName());
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        return view;

    };
}

 class ViewHolder {
     TextView txtTitle;
     ImageView imageView;
}
```

Comment: how many images you want to show in list.?

Comment: I have not decided the no .... say it can be n..... i am trying to learn .... 'File myPath = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null);' is causing to bring all files from directory ....

Comment: yes, it gives all files in your dir, then short list the images as you required n number of images from that.

Comment: how can i do that ? .... how can i short list to ones that i currently captured ?

Comment: you are creating the file with your time stamp like  "Image_" + timeStamp + "_";  save the time stamp in preferences when closing and opening your application, when you are re open the application get the list which file in between the time.., it bit tricky..

Answer (score 0):

try this, using `file.lastmodified()` method.

```
private ArrayList<String> getRecentImages(long from, long to,
            ArrayList<String> list) {
        ArrayList<String> sortedList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            File file = new File(list.get(i));
            long modified = file.lastModified();
            if (modified > from && modified <= to) {
                sortedList.add(list.get(i));
            }
        }
        return sortedList;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for info.... there is a musch simple way ....that is to store the images references globally in a array ...use that ...instead of directory looping thank you for info ...i cannot give [+1] because i don't have enough reputaion in stackoverflow

Comment: at that case, if you are closing the application and reopen the application global value dont have any data.